# i am unable to get my dropdown values after page refresh

Tags: spring, jsp

I am having 2 dropdowns.
1.cusotmer
2.environment

onchange of customer dropdown I am getting environment name using rest call and onchange method.

I am having one GO button.After clicking go button my page has to refresh.Based on selected customer and environment .I am getting some result.But that time my environment dropdown is  not having values. If I onchange my customer then its loading.

Problem is after page refresh my dropdown is not retaining values.

This is my code..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
            var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'environments',
                data : {
                    selectedcustomername : value1
                },
                success : function(result){
                    getEnvNames(result);
                }

            });
        });
    });


function getEnvNames(result){
    $('#environmentName').empty().append('<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>');
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {
        $("#environmentName").append("<option>" + value.environments_name +" - "+ value.environments_purpose + "</option>");

    });

}
```

```
 <b>Environment:</b>
                            <select  class="body"  name="environmentName" id="environmentName">                                                                                                                                                 
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>                                                                                                                                                      
                            <select> </span>
                         </td>
```

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/environments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public @ResponseBody String getEnvironmentNames(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws SQLException {

        request.setAttribute("selectedcustomername", selectedcustomername);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("environments", new Environments());
         List<Environments>  environmentnamesList= loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
         Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         System.out.println("gson"+gson);
         String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
         System.out.println("jsonString"+jsonString);
         return jsonString;
    }
```

This is my go button

```
<form:form method="get" action="retrieve" modelAttribute="customer" commandName="customer">

in between customer and environment dropdown ui..finally
 <input name="Submit" value="Go" type="submit" class="boldFontSize3" />
```

Comment: can you post your retrieve action method

Answer (score 0):

**solution1:**
do not reload the page, instead use ajax to populate data and present on ui

**solution2:**
use javascript cookies to store the current state of the dropdowns and read the cookie and set the dropdowns on page load.

using cookies:

html:

```
<select id='select1'><option value='set1'>set1</option></select>

<select id='select2'><option value='set2'>set2</option></select>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#select2').change(function(){

var select2=$(this).val()
var select1=$('#select2').val()

$.cookie("select1", select1)
$.cookie("select2", select2)

})

//page load

var select1=$.cookie("select1")|| "default"
var select2=$.cookie("select2")|| "default"

$('#select1').val(select1)
$('#select2').val(select2)

})
```

Comment: i con't stop the page loading..can you please tell me how to set the cookie for this one..i am new to java

Comment: i am using <form:form method="get" action="retrieve" modelAttribute="customer" commandName="customer">..Because of this one my page is refreshing..can tell me how to set the cookie

Comment: its simple, set the cookie using javascript on the button click or when selecting the second dropdown. Then read the cookie at page load and set the dropdowns.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please help with sample code

Comment: By using this $.cookie("select2", select2) i am storing just selected environment.But i want to store that entire dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to read the selected customer value in your controller retrieve action and set the related environments values to the model. So that you will get the dropdown values after page refresh also.